# Which installed Chrome extension gives error alert?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On load of some page I getting alert (`SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON`)
But in anonymous mode all clear, so it given by Chrome extension**s**.
Is there a fast way to check what it is, other then going by exclusion method?

Comment: 1) You can disable extensions progressively in halves until you find the one (it's called binary search algorithm). 2) Alternatively, open devtools and enable "Pause on exceptions", then reload the page, and keep clicking "play" until it reaches this error, then you'll have the id of the extension in the script's URL.

Comment: Thanks, DevTools > Sources > Pause on exceptions helped identify problem on someone's site. This should be answer

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check your extension in chrome://extension and see if it shows any error on pointed location
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB2Bp.jpg)

if any error button shown here! than click on it to resolve error!

and  [object object] is not valid json!

you can write only one value in these brackets []:

//its a right json format

`"objects":["objects"]`

and all of this json writes in this two brackets!  {}

Here is Example of My Extension Manifest file!

```
{
  "name": "Notify!",
  "description": "A Google Chrome extension!",
  "version": "1.7",
  "manifest_version": 3,

  "icons": {
    "128": "/assets/icons/128.png",
    "48": "/assets/icons/128.png",
    "16": "/assets/icons/128.png"
    },

"action": {
"default_icon": "/assets/icons/128.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "It's my title"
},

"background":{
"script": ["eventPage.js"]
//"service_worker": false
},
"content_scripts":[
{
"matches": ["http://*.google.com/*"],
"js": ["content.js","jquery-3.6.1.min.js"]

}
],

"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*.google.com/*"
]

}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I have more than 1 extension (I was thinking it was obvious)